# Immutable vs javascript arrays, objects - what's the right balance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm building out my stack with (among other things) react, redux, immutable. My redux store is built with immutable maps, lists. However, at the react component level its easier to manipulate normal js arrays and objects.

So what's the balance? Should the immutable objects from the state be converted to regular js for all components and data  passed back to the reducer converted back to immutable to update state?

I'm currently doing it on a component by component basis but would be interested to learn about any current (de facto) best practices.

Comment: In my opinion ImmutableJS adds a lot of overhead to a project. Yep, it brings a lot of benefits to the table, but I personally don't adopt it unless I am sure its benefits outweigh its coding overhead.  You could start out with an immutability helper library like `timm`, which gives you a mechanism to "update" native types in an immutable like manner.  Then you can simply pass along the native types and by convention not mutate them in your components.  http://guigrpa.github.io/timm/

Comment: Of course if you are already deep into implementation then my comment is less useful. :)

Comment: Immutable or another lib is aimed for good practicing. You can build without that. But sometimes it offers you some easy ways to get, update, compare, etc... your state. A simple example: would you prefer to write this "this.state.user && this.state.user.data && this.state.user.data.profile && this.state.user.data.profile.avatar" to be sure to not throwing an error when you try to get this.state.user.data.profile.avatar OR just state.getIn(['user', 'data', 'profile', 'avatar']) ? and this is just a simple use case

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I do agree that immutable adds a little more complexity that's why I'm trying to find the right balance. I don't believe in immutability by convention. It's like leaving all your money on a table and implementing trust by convention. Eventually your both your money and your immutability will be gone :)

Comment: In your reducers, you may use https://github.com/engineforce/ImmutableAssign, which is a lightweight immutable helper that allows you to continue working with POJO (Plain Old JavaScript Object) in your React components.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, embrace Immutable and stick to it. Even if it seems easier manipulate js data types at component level, the advantages that immutable gives you in term of good practice and performance are great.

If you use in your store immutable, use it in the components even.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** :

- Store is an `Immutable.Map`
- Store exposes data via `getters` or `selectors` transposing them to plain js object : `const getFooItem(state, itemId) => state.getIn(['item',itemId]).toJS()`
- Dumbs components consume data as plain js object via `props`

### Use `Immutable.js` for your redux Store

I think you should definitely use `Immutable.js` for you redux store since it's ensure you to keep an immutable store. It's less error prone than pure javascript, even with the new ES6 syntax. For example, let's say a slice of your state looks like this :

```
state = {
   items: {
       'id1': {...your_fo_object_with_id1...},
       'id2': {...your_fo_object_with_id2...},
       etc.
   }
}
```

Now you want to populate the item with `id2` so you're writting something like this :

```
return {
    ...state,
    items: {
        ...items, //Do not forget this line, if you do, no error will be thrown, but your state will be in a bad state since all others items will be lost 
        [action.id]: action.item
    }
}
```

Did you notice my comment ? If it's possible to make a ommitment like this (i.e, forget to copy the previous state), with such a big impact, you can be sure you're going to make it, sooner or later. Ask my how I know it...

With `Immutable.js` this kind of error is avoided by the syntax itself :

```
return state.updateIn(['items', 'id1'], () => Immutable.fromJS(action.item)))
```

### Use plain js object for your props

Here, it's more a personnal preference, but since you want to keep a maximum of your components as dumb as possible, why would they know that their props are `Immutable` object and know how to handle them ?

Generally it's tempting to use `Immutable.js` from props for the reference equality check used when shallow comparing props in order to avoid unecessary rendering. It's effectively very handy when you have very nested props *BUT* I think very nested props are a bad idea. Try to keep your components props as flat as possible, that make them less coupled with your data schema and more reusable.

### EDIT

As stated by Raj R in comments, you may use some `getters` or `selectors` to act as a bridge between your immutable store and your dumbs components. It's make perfect sense because `getters` or `selectors` are by definition tightly coupled to your store, so they can receive treat immutable data and open them to the external world via plain js object that will be consumed by your dumbs components.

Comment: Good point about keeping your components as dumb as possible. However, I do see the need for transforming your state data before presenting in the component. Whether it be as simple as filtering the items or creating a summary based on the items in the state. Depending on the level of transformation, it may be easier to toJSON() the state and proceed from there.

Comment: You're totally right, maybe I should update this answer by mentioning getters or selectors used to create a bridge between your immutable store and your dumbs components.

Comment: Nice - thanks for adding the update.